# Century Gothic font rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been having trouble for some time with Century Gothic on my website. It seems like when the `font-weight` is bold, **there is no difference between an l and an i character** (check the images).

[image]
how it looks

[image]
how it should look like

It is happening with all browsers (including Chrome and Firefox), and I am importing the font like so, for all of the different styles and weights with different files. Bold is like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicStd';
    src: url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and calling it on the body like so:

```
body {
  font-family: CenturyGothicStd, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, "Glyphicons Halflings", sans-serif;
}
```

I don't understand if the problem rellies on my website or on the font.
What could be triggering this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will need to add another font with the font facing looking something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothic';
    src: url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicStd/3099F9_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicBold';
    src: url('./fonts/CenturyGothicBold/3099F9_2_0.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/CenturyGothicBold/3099F9_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicBold/3099F9_2_0.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicBold/3099F9_2_0.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./fonts/CenturyGothicBold/3099F9_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I'm importing every variation
e: fixed the import snippet on the question

Comment: But what about Style Linking?
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/#style-linking